# data returned from custom hook returns `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The data is `undefined` even though it consoled the right data inside custom hook.

inside the code for the component below

`console.log("Live", content, status); //content is undefined, status is correct`

but inside hook

`console.log("arcontent", arContent); //prints correct data here`

```
// component
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useContent } from "@/components/hooks/useContent";

const Live = ({ title }) => {
  const { content, status } = useContent("king_of_the_birds");
  console.log("Live", content, status); //content is undefined, status is correct

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Content: {content}</div>
      <div>Status: {status}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Live;


//hook - useContent.js

const localCache = {};
const BASE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL;

async function requestArContent(title) {
  console.log("pinging server for content");

  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/books`);
    const json = (await res.json()) || {}; //{} so app doesn't crash if no network connection
    localCache[title] = json;
  } catch (error) {
    // ignore
    console.error(error);
  }
  return localCache[title];
}

export function useContent(title) {
  const [arContent, setArContent] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); //unloaded, loading, loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!title) {
        setArContent({});
      } else if (localCache[title]) {
        setArContent(localCache[title]);
      } else {
        setStatus("loading");
        await requestArContent(title);
        setArContent(localCache[title]);
        console.log("inside async useContent", value);
        setStatus("loaded");
      }
    })();
  }, [arContent, title]);

  console.log("arcontent", arContent); //prints correct data here

  return { arContent, status };
}
```

//

Comment: You're returning a parameter named `arContent` from `useContent`, but then trying to use a variable named `content` in `Live`. Try: `const { arContent, status } = useContent("king_of_the_birds");`

Comment: omg  thanks so much!